# Converting varchar to money

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar, currency

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBSP](
    [OS_PESO] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have this table name `tblBSP` with a column `OS_PESO`. Now, I have to `BULK INSERT` values for `OS_PESO`. Values for `OS_PESO` column would be something like this:

```
58,083.15 
2,000,000.00 
(2,004.84)
```

I have the following error:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I've seen questions that are similar to these hence, I've tried these, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
update tblBSP
set OS_PESO = (select convert(money,replace(OS_PESO,',','')))

--or 

update tblBSP
set OS_PESO = (select CAST(isnull(OS_PESO,0) as money))

--or

update tblBSP
set OS_PESO = (SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, OS_PESO), 1 ))
```

Thanks. ^^

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What about "(" and ")". You might want to replace  "(" with "-" and ")" with "".

Comment: Im using mysql.

Comment: Okay sure will try replacing it :) ty

Answer (score 0):

you can use this...for casting

**update tblBSP
set OS_PESO = (select CAST(OS_PESO AS decimal(18, 2)) )**

Comment: :'( I've tried it and this was what appeared. 
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurs due to the comma (',') in a string.

Try Following:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBSP
(
    `OS_PESO` varchar(100)

);

insert into tblBSP(`OS_PESO`)Values
('58,083.15');

insert into tblBSP(`OS_PESO`)Values
('2,000,000.00');

update tblBSP set `OS_PESO`=cast(replace(`OS_PESO`,',','') as decimal(15,2)) 

select *from tblBSP
```

**Output:**

[image]

[SQlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87044d/2)

Comment: Good day sir. Would values in parenthesis or the negative values also be converted to money? E.g (2,004.84)